# Node.js Date command creates incorrect date

Tags: node.js

I was experimenting with creating new dates in Node.js; for some reason it is giving me dates that are one day out.

```
date = new Date("17 Jul 1990");
Fri, 16 Jul 1990 23:00:00 GMT
```

huh???

Edit: I am using Node.js for windows v0.6.5, just downloaded and installed today.

Comment: Probably just it printing the date in your time zone. Try `date.toISOString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not one day, it one hour (look better). And it did it ok. It took your machine local timezone into account, but the string result shows GMT.

And it is only because what is written down in node REPL is `util.inspect(x)` (which uses `toUTCString()`), not `x.toString()`.

Just try `date.toString()` and you'll see everything is perfectly correct.

Comment: 1st paragraphy is a bit patronizing (probably not intentional), but the answer is correct.

Comment: Not intentional (at least I hope, subconscious is subconscious). Also, I simple don't like un-truths (and it is not a truth that the difference is one day), so I react to such things automatically.

Comment: I had a more detailed look at the problem after posting and realised that it was a GMT / BST problem. Hadn't realised about the REPL using toUTCString(). Thanks for that. Don't worry about possibly seeming patronising - gotta call things how you see them :-)